# Pausing Windows Service thread?

Tags: windows, service, thread-sleep

Here's an overview of what I'm aiming for:

I have a Windows Service that will, on start, check a specific database on that server for any available queues. If a queue is found, it must start processing (quite simple and straight forward). If no queues are found, I need the service to sort of "sleep" for 15 minutes and then "restart". If queues are found, start processing otherwise sleep another 15 minutes and "restart".

How can I go about doing this? I've looked at the System.Threading.Sleep method, but apparently that's very poor coding. I do understand that sleeping the thread, will block any consecutive methods from being executed, which is fine - as after the Sleep, the service will call the same method to "restart" processing.

I've also looked at System.Threading.Timer, but sometimes the system just stops the service completely. There's a few errors in the event viewer relating to some sort of exception, but when I manually start the service it starts processing the queues automatically - indicating there's nothing wrong with my coding.

What is the best way to suspend the Service thread for 15 minutes, then call the processing method again. It should stay in a loop of continuously checking for available queues. Once one is found, do the processing, and if none is found just sleep for 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want to sleep, you simply call [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx). In the most basic terms, your thread's main execution loop would look like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!queue.processItem())
        Thread.Sleep(...);
}
```

You should not call `Thread.Sleep` on the main service thread. Call it on a background thread. So the idea is that the main service thread stays alive and ready to process any service messages. And the background thread does the actual work.

And yes, sleeping is something to be avoided in general. Ideally you want a blocking queue that you can wait on in case it is empty. And then, when items are added to the queue, your thread will wake.

Comment: Note that the main service thread doesn't (necessarily) need to stay alive; the Service Manager creates its own thread to call the control handler function.  Of course, if your control handler function sends messages to the main service thread, then you'll need to be listening for them. :-)